# c++ primer chapter 3 exercise 3.20 vector over flow

Tags: c++, vector

I think I am getting a vector overflow.(?) However I do not know how to solve it. The exercise I am trying to complete states the following:

Exercise 3.20 Part 1: Read a set of integers into a vector. Print the sum of each pair of adjacent elements.

location of run time error:

```
for (int sum; v1 < ivec.size();++v1){  //executes for statement as long as v1 < ivec.size() is true.
    sum = ivec[v1] + ivec[v1 + 1]; // same as sum = ivec[0] + ivec[1].
    cout << sum << endl; sum = 0; // prints the result of sum = ivec[v1] + ivec[v1 + 1].
```

The code for the whole program is below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
vector<int> ivec;
decltype (ivec.size()) v1 = 0;
unsigned int i1 = 0;

while (cin >> i1){ ivec.push_back(i1);} // receive input and stores into ivec.

for (int sum; v1 < ivec.size();++v1){  //executes for statement as long as v1 < ivec.size() is true.
    sum = ivec[v1] + ivec[v1 + 1]; // same as sum = ivec[0] + ivec[1], v1 is now = 1.
    cout << sum << endl; sum = 0; // prints the result of sum = ivec[v1] + ivec[v1 + 1].
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through with a debugger. Notice what you're trying to do with the vector.

Comment: What do you think `v1 + 1` is when `v1 == ivec.size() - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you will read one past the end of your vector in the very last iteration.  This is because you are accessing ivec[v1 + 1] in the loop, but v1 is allowed to be the index of the last element.

You can fix this by changing your loop condition to be (v1 < ivec.size() - 1).

Answer (score 0):

I worked through the same problem and was able to solve it using iterators. See code below.

```
// Exercise_3.24.cpp : Read a set of integers into a vector.
// Print the sum of each pair of adjacent elements.
// Change your program so that it prints the sum of the first and last elements,
// followed by the sum of the second and second-to-last, and so on.
// Redo the last exercise from 3.3.3 (p. 105) using iterators.

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    // read a set of integers into a vector
    vector<int> ivec{ 1,3,4,2,6,8,53,23,562,2 };    // list initialization
    
    // print the sum of each pair of adjacent elements
    for (auto iter = ivec.cbegin() + 1; iter != ivec.cend(); iter++)
    {
        cout << *(iter - 1) << " + " << *iter << " = ";
        cout << *(iter - 1) + *iter << endl;
    }
    
    cout << endl;

    // iterator equal to the last element in the vector
    auto n = ivec.cbegin() + ivec.size() - 1;   // one less size because subscripts start at 0
    
    // print the sum of the first and last elements
    // followed by the sum of the second and second-to-last, and so on
    for (auto iter = ivec.cbegin(); iter < n; iter++)
    {
        cout << *iter << " + " << *n << " = ";
        cout << *iter + *n << endl;
        n = n - 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```